# Connection to Shared Diskstations

Tags: sharing

I have two Synology Diskstations. One of them (diskstation-8) is always connected to my mac pro. For some reason the other one (diskstation-5) is not and I need always to click on it when I want the disk station connected. I have recently transfered to El Capitan. I would like to have my disk station-5 connected at login and stay connected (like my diskstation-8 ... but I don't remember how I fixed that)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dropped an AppleScript into my Login Items.

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        -- open location ("afp://DiskStation.local/Archive")
        -- open location ("afp://DiskStation.local/Documents")
        -- open location ("afp://DiskStation.local/Media")
        mount volume "afp://DiskStation.local/Archive"
        mount volume "afp://DiskStation.local/Documents"
        mount volume "afp://DiskStation.local/Media"
        mount volume "afp://DiskStation.local/Pictures"
        on error number n
          display alert ("Error " & n & " on network share mount")
    end try
end tell
```